# Reflection added Delegate not firing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reflection

This is the code.

For example purposes, NewButton will have the name "Add", the SubMenuButtonNamesList is a list of strings containing the names of the buttons that I will be creating, afterwards I wanted to add the handler to these buttons based on the methods found in the mainwindow, matched by their names.

I think I did it properly since the button does have this handler added, but when I click the button nothing happens, it should show me a messagebox saying "yes".

```
public void Add_Method(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yes");
}
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Create all sub-menu buttons
    foreach (var element in SubMenuButtonNamesList)
    {
        Button NewButton = new Button()
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Color { A = 100, R = 231, G = 233, B = 245 }),
            FontFamily = new FontFamily("Century Gothic"),
            Content = element,
            FontSize = 14,
            Height = 30,
            Width = Double.NaN,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };

        NewButton.Name = element.Trim();
        
        try
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(MainWindow).GetMethod(NewButton.Name + "_Method");
            Delegate myDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MouseButtonEventHandler), this, method);
            NewButton.MouseLeftButtonDown += (MouseButtonEventHandler)myDelegate;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        SubMenuButtonsList.Add(NewButton);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't get an exception? You have empty `catch`.

Comment: @Roman yes, I do not get an exception for the "Add" button, the others get an exception because there is no method created for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the MouseLeftButtonDown event for Button (didn't check for anything else), if added this way will not fire, however if you do it for the Click event, it will fire properly, see below snippet of the modifications:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(MainWindow).GetMethod(NewButton.Name + "_Method");
Delegate myDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(RoutedEventHandler), this, method);
NewButton.Click += (RoutedEventHandler)myDelegate;
```

And the method:

```
public void Add_Method(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Yes");
}
```